# Are there any non-Java, web-based, embeddable miners?

Tags: website-integration, webminer

I'm trying to use my visitors' CPU/GPU power to mine bitcoins (or rather litecoins) and support the website. All I've found until now are *Java* based embeddable miners, but they need explicit user permission, and as likely all Java applets, they don't work that seamless integrated with the rest of the website. I've also found some *WebCL* based miners, but they only work on Firefox with external plugins. The speed doesn't matters that much, as there are multiple users.

**Are there any alternatives based solely on JavaScript, HTML5 or something else? Is that even possible?**

*Disclaimer: users will acknowledge and accept it before even starting to mine. **Please, no moral judging.*** 
Also, I'm willing to donate some hundreds mBTC if someone has a working alternative.

Answer (score 4):

Some quick Google searching uncovered these:

- Bitcoin Plus [Bitcoin Miner for Websites](http://www.bitcoinplus.com/miner/embeddable)
- [Hamiyoca](https://code.google.com/p/hamiyoca)
- [jsMiner](https://github.com/jwhitehorn/jsMiner)

The general feeling, though, is that it is [impractical](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10320/how-useful-is-a-javascript-miner).

Comment: Yeah, I've already fiddled with those... Bitcoinplus miner is java based, Hamiyoca is two years old and doesn't works and jsMiner is also two years old and also doesn't works =(

Comment: None of these work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Hamiyoca.

It isn't worth it, but I have gotten Hamiyoca to work with some getwork servers.