# Creating a bitcoin/litecoin miner with Javascript

Tags: client, development, algorithms

I am a web developer and looking for well written technical documents about how bitcoin/litecoin works, what is the workflow, what is the algorithm and how can I write a miner from scratch by using JavaScript (or similar).

It will be a kind of hobby/portfolio project, so I am not worrying about the performance and the other possible issues.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't written specifically about mining, but I wrote a comprehensive document that a web developer can follow. It also contains the library on the page so you can experiment along in the console.

Here it is:

[Generating a Bitcoin Address in JavaScript](http://procbits.com/2013/08/27/generating-a-bitcoin-address-with-javascript)

Hopefully it helps you some on your quest to learn more about Bitcoin.

Answer (score 2):

Why reinvent the wheel?

I think there are several simple javascript miners out there, so I won't bother telling you more than to google it (or to duckduckgo it, if you prefer).

But whilst we are at it: Would you believe people have gone far beyond it and found a way to program a javascript-based miner using GPUs, as pointed out in [an answer on bitcoin.stackexchange](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10320/how-useful-is-a-javascript-miner/10327#10327)? That project is [hosted here](https://code.google.com/p/hamiyoca/).