# npm / node mining for litecoins

Tags: litecoin, server

**UPDATED AND CLARIFIED AND SIMPLIFIED**

I'm looking through npmjs.org - My thought is can a node.js server mine (without a graphics card just using its own possessing power?) If so (there are a lot of modules for different things to do with statum) has anyone else done this?

I'm having difficulty understanding things with these npm modules on how to get them hooked up the same as my batch file (.bat) currently using cgminner ( I don't want to use cgminner just node.js)

my .bat for cgminer looks something like this:

```
cgminer.exe --scrypt -u example.1 -p x -o stratum+tcp://united.wemineltc.com:3334 --gpu-platform 0 -w 256 -v 1 -I 17 -g 1 -l 1 --thread-concurrency 6496
```

1. does anyone use node.js for this
2. can someone show me which npm modules mine
3. can someone show me how to add my bat details to a npm node module js script

Thanks Guys!

Comment: I recommend you clarify your question down to a single thing like "How to mine using node.js", it's hard to interpret this.

Comment: I have updated and clarified.. Please unhold, thank you

Comment: This question could be simplified down to "Is it efficient to use Node.js for mining? If so how?". All the extra info, the youtube video, mentioning your friend, is all very unnecessary and still very hard to interpret.

Comment: ok I will change now...

Comment: That's a good edit there, we have to do this because improperly worded questions will show up on all kinds of searches and confuse people who have the same question.

Comment: cazala coin-hive is the only one that can mine cryptonight coins (e.g. monero) via node.js

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this is yes, it will. Mining can be done on most turing-complete languages like Javascript. But the true question is [how useful is a JavaScript miner.](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/10320/how-useful-is-a-javascript-miner/10327#10327) Not to mention Node.js is optimized towards asynchronicity, something which heavy math equations that mining requires aren't. Node.js [isn't suitable for CPU heavy tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16974557/why-is-node-js-not-suitable-for-heavy-cpu-apps) but it flies when dealing with many requests at the same time. For this reason there aren't many miners built on Node.js/Javascript. A miner written in C++ is your best bet, such as CGMiner.